# computer autometic get turned off while training using object detection api on local machine

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have 10K images for training and validation each, using SSDMObileNEt on the local machine with 4GB ram Nvidia Geforce 1050 ti GPU, I usually train model in the night, before sleep I start it, when I train more than 5 steps, I found my PC turned off, and the training does not take place properly, why is this so?
Batch size I have kept is 16.

Comment: Please add some log files to understand what went wrong during training. Right now your question is quite vague.

Comment: from where Can I get log files, I start draining before my sleep in the night, when I wake up in the morning I found ny turned off laptop, I noticed that after tuning off I was very hot.

Comment: I'm assuming you have some python script with `print` messages. Replace those `print` commands with [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) and output those logs to a file. Then you can inspect that log files later. Here is some [boilerplate](https://github.com/saratrajput/runcom_backups/blob/master/boilerplate/logging_bp.py) to get you started.